# Translating VB.NET Method Call to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services

I can't seem to figure how to properly convert the following VB.NET code into C#, where I will be declaring a web service object and then ultimately using a function to return the data I need. I have the webservice created in my project: http://mmm-acctgdev.abc.com/Central_Locating/Service/Locating.asmx

VB.NET web service declaration:

```
Dim oFind As New com.abc.mmm_acctgdev.Locating

//*Need to convert this into something a C# form can use
```

VB function call :

```
retXML = oFind.GetLocationByNum(txtFNum.Text)

//*need this call in c#
```

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ for converting VB.NET to C#

Answer (score 3):

```
var oFind = new com.abc.mmm_acctgdev.Locating();
var retXML = oFind.GetLocationByNum(txtFNum.Text);
```